# How to check if files in a directory change(added/removed/modified) in chef for linux hosts

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to write a chef recipe where I need to put some logic to detect if files in a directory change(added/removed/modified) in chef for Linux hosts and if any change happens I can probably use notify to restart the service.

please help me by providing simple logic's as there would not be drastic changes in files.

`/local/filebeat/logs` is the directory and when ever new files are added in to it i want the filebeat service to be restarted.

```
directory '/local/filebeat/logs' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  notifies :restart, 'service[filebeat]'
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more explicit and show us, what you've tried so far (your code). I don't get your point. Are you aware of [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications) in Chef?

Comment: thanks for your response, i have edited my question and added what i am trying to do, i am very new to chef and i gone through the documentation for  notifications in chef. my real question here would be how do i tell chef to check for modification in the directory /local/filebeat/logs

Answer (score 1):

You would use Chef's notifications feature: `notifies` and `subscribes`. Each resource triggers its notifications when it is "updated" (the precise definition of which varies for each resource) which can then be used to run actions on other resources, in this case you would want a `:restart` action on a `service` resource most likely.

Comment: thanks for your response, from the example i have posted in the question service would be restarted only if directory is not present on the node or in its first run on the node, if the directory exists and new files are added in it chef would not restart the service since directly already exists. how to restart the service only if new files are added or removed in the directory?

Comment: You would need to manage each of those files with Chef, it can only track things matched to resources.